# How to find less frequenlty accessed files in HDFS

Tags: hive, hdfs, cloudera-navigator

Beside using Cloudera Navigator, how can I find the less frequently accessed files, in HDFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for [the time a file was last accessed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1869) (open, read, etc.), because as longer in the past the file would be less accessed.

Whereby you can do this in Linux quite simple via [ls -l -someMoreOptions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140406/), in HDFS more work is necessary.

Maybe you could monitor the `/hdfs-audit.log` for `cmd=open` of the mentioned file. Or you could implement a small function to read out the `FileStatus.getAccessTime()` and as mentioned under [Is there anyway to get last access time of HDFS files?](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Is-there-anyway-to-get-last-access-time-of-hdfs-files/m-p/153380) or [How to get last access time of any files in HDFS?](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-get-last-access-time-of-any-files-in-hdfs/ta-p/244503) in Cloudera Community.

In other words, it will be necessary to create a small program which scans all the files, read out the properties

```
...
status = fs.getFileStatus(new Path(line));
...   
long lastAccessTimeLong = status.getAccessTime();
Date lastAccessTimeDate = new Date(lastAccessTimeLong);
...
```

and order it. It that you will be able find files which were not accessed for long times.